# Force Doctrine to Join

Tags: doctrine-orm

Hi I'm new with doctrine 2.

In my case I got an action entity with id, name, action_type_id and an action_type entity with id, name.

I got 2 action entities and the action_type is a manyToOne relation.

If I now use doctrines findAll method a select for action and 2 additional action_type selects will be executed.

```
$actions = $entityManager->getRepository(\Model\Action::class)->findAll();
```

Can I force doctrine to join instead to create new selects or do I have to write own DQLs for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set fetch=EAGER on the relationship with doctrine. Depending on where you store your config there is a different way to do it. In annotations you just add fetch="EAGER" to the orm annotation.

Comment: this works only if I dont cache it.If I use     $cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\FilesystemCache('cache/doctrine');
I also get 3 selects.